# Grails define custom error message for command object

Tags: validation, grails

I am writing a Grails (2.3.3 currently) application and have created a validateable command object similar to the following:

```
@Validateable
class MyCustomCommand {
  String name

  static constraints = {
    name blank: false
  }
}
```

In my `i18n/messages.properties` file I defined the following properties to override the default error messages.

```
MyCustomCommand.name.blank=Name must be provided.
MyCustomCommand.name.null=Name must be provided.
```

Which per the Grails documentation should be of the format `[Class Name].[Property Name].[Constraint Code]` as I have done. When I run my application if I leave the value blank I still get the default message for a null property.

I also tried following the example of the default messages and defining them a follows, but still get the default message.

```
MyCustomCommand.name.blank.message=Name must be provided.
MyCustomCommand.name.null.message=Name must be provided.
```

I am assuming that I am missing something simple here, but have yet to stumble upon what. Any suggestions on what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple indeed. Message should look like:

```
myCustomCommand.name.blank=Name must be provided.
myCustomCommand.name.nullable=Name must be provided.


//className.propertyName.blank (camelCase with first letter of class name lower)
```

Comment: I believe this was the first variation I tried, and I just now tried it and still got the default.

Comment: oops I missed the null part while concerning all about lower case. Rectified. :)

Answer (score 1):

So, as I anticipated it was something simple. I was using the defaults as an example which used `null` where as what I really needed was `nullable`. Which does make sense as that matches the constraint name.

Therefore the correct version is:

```
myCustomCommand.name.blank=Name must be provided.
myCustomCommand.name.nullable=Name must be provided.
```